# .htaccess AddOutputFilter fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently enable GZIP like so:

```
# gzip compression
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json
</ifmodule>
```

This produces response headers like such:

[image]

Notice that `Content-Encoding` is set to `gzip`, and that `Vary` is also set.

Now, I'd like to use code from [this .htaccess file](https://github.com/sergeychernyshev/.htaccess/blob/master/.htaccess), which supposedly improves performance, but when I replace my code above with this:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compression: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#GzipCompression
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/atom+xml
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/x-component
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/xml

# The following MIME types are in the process of registration
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/xslt+xml
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE image/svg+xml

# The following MIME types are NOT registered
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/mathml+xml
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/rss+xml

# JavaScript has various MIME types
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/ecmascript
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE text/javascript

# .ico files and other compressible images
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE image/bmp
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE image/tiff
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/pdf

# compressible fonts (.woff is already compressed)
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
</IfModule>
```

the response headers for the same file request become this:

[image]

The `Content-Encoding: gzip` header is no longer present. Also, `Transfer-Encoding`, and `Vary` are also gone, now.

What's going on here? Why does this new code fail to gzip the file?

Comment: [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) (AddOutputFilter) uses  also [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) (AddOutputFilterByType) to compress the output, so what could be the reason to use it?

Comment: @faa What are you saying? That the above code shouldn't work?

Comment: Not exactly. What I am trying to say is what would be the purpose of using last snippet when you are already using the right directives directly. AddOutputFilter is not a `mod_deflate` directive and therefore has to use that mode to compress, while AddOutputFilterByType is indeed a `mod_deflate` directive.

Comment: @faa So you're saying that the latter code (the one that uses `AddOutputFilter`) is not the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`AddOutputFilterByType` accepts media types, which in this case is:

```
application/json
```

`AddOutputFilter` accepts file extensions, which in this case is:

```
json
```

**References**

- [Core Apache HTTP Server features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html)
- [mod mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_mime.html)
- [mod filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_filter.html)
- [Configuring Server MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types)
- [Common HTTP Implementation Problems(CHIPS)](https://www.w3.org/TR/chips/)
- [Authoritative MetaData](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/mime-respect)